# Tangent of a sine - can it disprove the marginal value theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The [marginal value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_value_theorem) is partly explained by this text and graph:

> As animals forage in patchy systems, they balance resource intake, traveling time, and foraging time. Resource intake within a patch diminishes with time, as shown by the solid curve in the graph to the right. The curve follows this pattern because resource intake is initially very fast, but slows as the resource is depleted. Traveling time is shown by the distance from the leftmost vertical dotted line to the y-axis. Optimal foraging time is modeled by connecting this point on the x-axis tangentially to the resource intake curve. Doing so maximizes the ratio between resource intake and time spent foraging and traveling.

[image: A graph from wikipedia demonstrating the marginal value theorem]

Say the (resource intake) curve is a part of a sine function (which resembles the curve in the illustration), and we divide the y values by 4 (or any other value), the tangent would still hit the same *expected transit time* point. This means that regardless of the magnitude of the cumulative resource intake, the optimal time in patch remains the same, which could practically mean the animal will die.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea what your final paragraph is saying. What do you mean by "divide the $y$ values by 4"? If you mean just rescale the whole thing in $y$: why would you want to do that? The resource intake curve should depend on (a) how fast the animal eats and (b) how much stuff there is for it to eat. If you are just going to make the hump smaller by taking food away from the patch, then obviously the animal will die...

Comment: Even though the text and the figure are from Wikipedia, I'm inclined to call this  voodoo mathematics.

Comment: @WillieWong Divide by 4 means instead of y=sin(x) you have y = sin(x)/4. As for your other points - it makes perfect sense; yet it is possible that on one patch the curve will look like this, but on another patch the food is much sparser - in turn, this will scale down the curve, and one possibility is that the tangent will still yield the same optimal time. So two patches, the second twice as sparse as the first, yet the optimal time is the same - doesn't seem to follow.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter the only real mathematical question here is whether a scaled sine will yield the same tangent points. The marginal value theorem is a *theorem* and has been demonstrated in other walks of life, such as online user behaviour (the time users spend on a site correlates to the time they assume it will take them to find the information elsewhere, as the MVT predict).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: why? The MVT says nothing more than that if $f\in C^1_0([0,\infty))$, then the local maxima of $f(t)/t$ satisfies $t_0 f'(t_0) = f(t_0)$. As a mathematical statement it is perfectly fine (albeit of freshman calculus level).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [clarified question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793892/tangent-of-a-sine-can-it-disprove-the-marginal-value-theorem?noredirect=1#comment1645750_793892):

> the only real mathematical question here is whether a scaled sine will yield the same tangent points.

Yes, affine transformations of Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{E}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ will preserve:

1. tangency of curves
2. straight lines
3. intersections of curves

thus in particular your affine transformation of $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y/4)$ will preserve the optimal time.

---

This, however, is a different question than which appears in the title of your post. As you mentioned yourself, the MVT is a theorem, so you can't **disprove** it. What you have a problem with is how one applies the theorem. The naive manner in which the theorem is stated assumes, essentially, that animals live in $\mathbb{R}^1$ with a patch of food some distance away.

Most land-animals in fact live effectively in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So one not only has to optimize over time spent foraging but also optimize over which direction one travels.

Now, even in one dimension one can have two patches of food, one to the left and one to the right. This brings up another point: as the name of the theorem suggests, it is about "marginal values", which are essentially derivatives in calculus. The derivative test in calculus is famously only capable of detecting **local extrema**. The MVT tells you that if your rabbit has decided to head toward the smaller pile of food, then the best strategy, given that this choice has already been made, is to eat for a certain time.